# I've been trying to set system property for chrome driver in php through command prompt

Tags: php, selenium, facebook-php-webdriver

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\xampp\htdocs\seleniumtest\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

but im getting

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

can someone help me through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with double slash instead of single.

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\seleniumtest\\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

or with forward slash like,

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/xampp/htdocs/seleniumtest/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```